# Can "3D printer" refer to both types of printers?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, technical

Ignoring the social norm:

May one technically call a printer, that exists in 3D space but prints in 2D space, a "3D printer", where "3D" is an adjective and "printer" being the noun?

In addition, is it fine to also say "3D printer", where both "3D" and "printer" together acts as a single noun describing the printer that can print in 3D space?

In summary, may one say "3D printer" to technically refer to both a printer and a 3D printer?

Comment: If you want to be extremely technical, you can use ***3D printer*** to describe both a printer that prints a 3-dimensional object and a printer that is a 3-dimensional object itself. That being said, it would be highly confusing to do so and I don't really see a beneficial reason to call regular printer a ***3D printer***. Nobody assumes that a ***printer*** is going to be 2D...

Comment: I agree with Hank. It's highly redundant to refer to a regular printer as a 3D printer as they are already assumed so. I wouldn't recommend it, although it's _technically_ correct. Context would be important.

Comment: Yes, I realize the lack of benefit from doing so, but I just wanted to clear up a friendly argument between a friend and I.

Thank you both!

Comment: Technically, everything that's printed is 3D, since all atoms occupy volume.  So yes, all printers are 3D printers.  Technically correct, the best kind of correct...

Comment: This question feels like a setup for a Steven Wright joke

Comment: You can do that, but it would be very confusing, it would be as bad as referring to a printer with colour printing capability but with a case made from black plastic and white plastic as a black and white printer. If you were going to be really pedantic you could call it a 4 dimentional printer since it exists and operates in three dimentions but also exists and operates in time;  but that would just be silly.

Comment: Sure you can.  But remember that a "digital printer" must be one that prints with it's fingers.  (Or, if it's 3D, it prints fingers.)

Comment: If it's an electrostatic dot matrix printer, call it an electrostatic dot matrix printer.

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing *grammatically* wrong with saying "3D printer" to refer to a regular printer; however, practically, you can't ignore the social norm.

Imagine this conversation:

> **me:** "I just bought a 3D car."
>   **my friend:** "What's a 3D car?"
>   **me:** "It's a car."

If your adjectives cause confusion rather than clarity, it is not "fine".

Comment: As well, it may be the case that someday 3d printers will become the norm and thus people start using the term '2d printers' to refer to old-fashioned printers and perhaps even 'printer' to refer to a '3d printer'.